# Knockout computed subscription is not triggered during cypress automation script

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, cypress

I have two textbox and a span where the result is shown.

```
Date: <input data-bind="value: dateValue"/>
Number: <input data-bind="value: dateValue"/>
Result : <span data-bind="text: calculatedValue">Result Should shown here</span>
```

KnockoutObservables are for "Date" and "Number" input fields. What ever Number user enters "3" then Computed function "Adds 3 days" to the "entered Date".

Knockout Computed subscription is on the "calculatedValue" i.e on result span.

Above functionality is working fine in the application but the computed method is not trigger correctly or calculated correctly during cypress automation script.
Where I type the date and number value to the input value.

But the calculation result shows nothing.

NOTE: the above mentioned is pseudo code. Syntax, binding and calculation logic is perfectly fine. Application is working perfectly. problem is during cypress autoamtion.

Cypress script psuedo code:-

```
cy.get("targetDateInput").clear().type("07/08/2018").type("{enter}");
cy.get("targetNumberInput").clear().type("6").type("{enter}");

cy.get("targetCalculatedValueDiv").children("span").should(($span) => {
    expect($span[0].innerHTML).to.contain("07/14/2018");
});
```

But it fails.

Comment: did you try adding logging inside your `computed`? if not, add `console.log('someString')` to make sure that the `computed` doesn't fire. Please update with your results.

Comment: Yes, Today I tried putting the console.log() inside my computed functions which are called for calculations and found that they are not triggered when the test fails and sometimes they are trigger (randomly the test is getting passed ).

Comment: It seems there's a hidden error that's causing what you're describing. Please wrap all of your code inside a `try-catch` blocks, and log exceptions to console. I guess you'll find some errors.

Comment: @PrashantKankhara, Do you still remember how you solved this? I think I am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Can you publish example on jsfiddle or another sandboxes?

I think, you can try use method [`notifySubscribers()`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) or [`valueHasMutated()`](https://forums.asp.net/t/2056128.aspx?What%20is%20the%20use%20of%20valueHasMutated%20in%20Knockout%20js) for notify view about changes.

Comment: But, its not working only in cypress automation - Its working perfectly fine in the application. If you mean to use notifySubscribers() or value HasMutated() in cypress script then it will break the responsibility of Automation. One Strange thing I found it. IF I keep the developer tools (dev tools - chrome) open (NOTE: No debugging point) then its working fine and with the same code, If I didn't keep the dev tools open then It will not trigger and hence the assertion is failed.


Strange if you read but I was shock when I saw practically..